# Silent Push Notification in iOS from Java APNS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications, javaapns

Push notification working properly in app from Java APNS,

But one notification in payload with

```
{
    aps =     {
        "content-available" = 1;
    };
    key = value;
    key = value;
    key = value;
}
```

This is not working in any state of app in iPhone 7, working in other devices, also check with battery mode.

From sender we see log and check response it's sending, but not received in device. 
What was the reason for particular device or state ??
i have searched over web but see almost same content which i m using, 
i got data in     `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)`
 this function when device receive any kind of push notification.

Comment: are you registering notification?

Comment: @SunilPrajapati means what registering ? i m getting others not this one only..